# Improving IC parameters

Tags: audio, amplifier, integrated-circuit, speakers, class-d

There are varied IC's to sift through to get to the one that matches a designers requirement. So i was wondering if its possible to improve an IC parameters, take for eg THD+N, to at-least an acceptable value.

As an example, for IC [TA2020](http://www.e-ele.net/DataSheet/TA2020.pdf), its THD+N shoots to 10% at 25W. Can it be brought down below 5%. Similarly its dynamic range or efficiency or channel separation.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, a chip supplier is going to paint the most reasonable portrait of their devices that is possible and, usually provide enough info to help achieve the targets of the designer. This usually means, no, you can't take a device that has such and such a spec and hope you can find a way of significantly improve on it.

Why would they undersell ?